# Proper Rails low-level caching with concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, caching, concurrency

I want to run my Rails 5 app on Puma. I use low-level caching and suppose the way to have thread-safe caching:

```
# somewhere in a model ...

@@mutex = Mutex.new

def nice_suff
  Rails.cache.fetch("a_key") do
    @@mutex.synchronize do
      Rails.cache.fetch("a_key", 60) do
        Model.stuff.to_a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Will this be working fine?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this synchronization?

Comment: I think, that only one thread will will build a record for cache. I suppose that I will stuck in a case when several threads will execute `Model.stuff.to_a` and I cannot imagine consequences))

Comment: This will stop working as soon as you have two machines.

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure I understood right about 2 machines... But in general, I expect that the first stucked thread will create the record, and yes, all other will wait. and when mutex opens - all waitings threads will get record from cache.

Comment: Two separate servers running the same app code. You know, scaling out.

Comment: Yes, but separate servers do have separate processes and addresses and @@mutex (in my case), do they not? I'he read your answer `:race_condition_ttl` - this is awesome solution!

Comment: "have separate processes and addresses and @@mutex" - yes, they do. I meant "will stop working" as in "this will no longer prevent hammering database with the same [expensive] request".

Comment: Ok, but why they do hammer if they will stuck on mutex and then will take records from cache?

Comment: because separate machines and separate mutexes.

Comment: You are right, exactly)) Thanks)

Comment: Anyhow, just use `race_condition_ttl` and try not to get into writing concurrency-managing code. Properly doing it is very hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to handle concurrent cache access is already built-in.

```
  val_1 = cache.fetch('foo', race_condition_ttl: 10.seconds) do
    Model.stuff.to_a
  end
```

> Setting `:race_condition_ttl` is very useful in situations where a cache entry is used very frequently and is under heavy load. If a cache expires and due to heavy load several different processes will try to read data natively and then they all will try to write to cache. To avoid that case the first process to find an expired cache entry will bump the cache expiration time by the value set in `:race_condition_ttl`. Yes, this process is extending the time for a stale value by another few seconds. Because of extended life of the previous cache, other processes will continue to use slightly stale data for a just a bit longer. In the meantime that first process will go ahead and will write into cache the new value. After that all the processes will start getting the new value. The key is to keep `:race_condition_ttl` small.

Comment: Awesome build-in solution! Thanks!